# How to generate a matrix of cosines for all possible pairs of vectors from two separate lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute efficiently in Python a matrix containing the cosine of all pairs vectors from two separate arrays. It would be a matrix A of shape `(M,N)` while the considered vectors are 2-D `[x, y]` ndarrays and thus the arrays containing them are of shape `(M,2)` and `(N,2)` :

```
u = [u0, ..., uM]
v = [v0, ..., vN]

A = [[cos(u0,v0), cos(u0,v1), ....     ],
    ...
    [...                  .., cos(uM,vN)]]
```

It is a pretty simple code with a `for` loop, but in my case it is called many times and I hope to improve my algorithm's performance by using a vectorized way of proceeding using numpy arrays ideally, yet I am open to suggestions.

I tried achieving this result by creating first a matrix using `np.meshgrid()`, but it gives odd results for 2-D vectors (lists of shape (6,4) instead of (3,2)):

```
AC_vectors = np.array([[69., 40.],[187.3, 35.], [12., 80]])
AB_vectors = np.array([[22., 150.],[42.5, 20.7]])

np.meshgrid(AB_vectors, AC_vectors)
[array([[ 22. , 150. ,  42.5,  20.7],
       [ 22. , 150. ,  42.5,  20.7],
       [ 22. , 150. ,  42.5,  20.7],
       [ 22. , 150. ,  42.5,  20.7],
       [ 22. , 150. ,  42.5,  20.7],
       [ 22. , 150. ,  42.5,  20.7]]), array([[ 69. ,  69. ,  69. ,  69. ],
       [ 40. ,  40. ,  40. ,  40. ],
       [187.3, 187.3, 187.3, 187.3],
       [ 35. ,  35. ,  35. ,  35. ],
       [ 12. ,  12. ,  12. ,  12. ],
       [ 80. ,  80. ,  80. ,  80. ]])]
```

Whereas with objects (thus the input arrays being a 1-D array) it behaves as expected :

```
AB_vectors = [Vector(x,y) for x,y in[[22., 150.], [42.5, 20.7]]]
AC_vectors = [Vector(x,y) for x,y in[[69., 40.], [187.3, 35.], [12., 80]]]

np.meshgrid(AB_vectors, AC_vectors)
[array([[Vector(x=22.0, y=150.0), Vector(x=42.5, y=20.7)],
       [Vector(x=22.0, y=150.0), Vector(x=42.5, y=20.7)],
       [Vector(x=22.0, y=150.0), Vector(x=42.5, y=20.7)]], dtype=object), array([[Vector(x=69.0, y=40.0), Vector(x=69.0, y=40.0)],
       [Vector(x=187.3, y=35.0), Vector(x=187.3, y=35.0)],
       [Vector(x=12.0, y=80), Vector(x=12.0, y=80)]], dtype=object)]
```

I hoped then to use a vectorized version of cosine with dot products and norms to compute the matrix, but I cannot figure an efficient way to bypass meshgrid() to generate a matrix of pairs `[ui,vj]`.

Ideally, there would be a way to directly generate the matrix without creating first a matrix of all possible pairs.

Comment: Most likely numpy solution will be slower and it will still use some kind of for loop under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the pairwise cosine between vectors you can just use the direct formula without generating (explicitly) each pair. The pairwise component of the computation is expressed as a matrix multiplication.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [69., 40.],
    [187.3, 35.], 
    [12., 80]
])
B = np.array([
    [22., 150.],
    [42.5, 20.7]
])

A = A / np.linalg.norm(A, axis=-1)[:, None]
B = B / np.linalg.norm(B, axis=-1)[:, None]

A @ B.T

> array([[0.62176578, 0.99740007],
>       [0.32438716, 0.96416838],
>       [0.99999468, 0.56640008]])
```

The (i, j) cell of the matrix contains the cosine similarity of the i-th vector and the j-th vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a meshgrid of the indexes and then use that to create all the combinations. From there, you can compute the dot products and divide by the norms to get the cosine of the angle between the vectors.

```py
import numpy as np

u = np.array([[69.,40.], [187.3, 35.], [12., 80]])
v = np.array([[22., 150.], [42.5, 20.7]])
norm_u = np.linalg.norm(u, axis=1)
norm_v = np.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)

def mesh_cosine(u, v):
    norm_u = np.linalg.norm(u, axis=1)
    norm_v = np.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)
    
    n = u.shape[0]
    m = v.shape[0]
    U, V = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, n), np.arange(0, m))
    
    res = np.sum(u[U.ravel()]*v[V.ravel()], axis=1)
    res /= norm_u[U.ravel()]*norm_v[V.ravel()]
    
    return res.reshape(n,m)

print(mesh_cosine(u, v))
```